# Use metadata within SSIS package

Tags: ssis, metadata, biml

I have the following problem:
We have a case where we need to import several dozen, if not hundreds, of uniquely structured source files with SSIS. Perfect opportunity to use BIML for this. We do not have metadata information for the files as is, so I need to get them - not manually, file by file, though.
So I thought, easy, build a table with filepaths, use BIML to create a package with the source connection, SSIS identifies metadata (maybe not 100% correctly) and I can use this metadata (column name, datatype, length, etc.) to initially persist in a metadata table for further use.

But: there seems to be no way to achieve this. While I can view the metadata and even paste it to the clipboard in SSDT, I cannot get it to the pipeline. Tried a script component as well (not my best skill), can get everything BUT the column name in ProcessInput, but can't create an output.

So: is there any known way of achieving this? Googled for several hours already to no avail.

Comment: Are you trying to create the metadata generation and the data load using the same Biml solution?  Biml can only create objects that it is able to validate itself at generation.  You should generate your metadata with one Biml solution and then reference it with a second solution.

Comment: @iamdave no, the metadata creation would be a separate package only run once initially and then on demand if any changes in the metadata occur. They would then be persisted and the BIML solution will always run on this persisted metadata table.

Comment: In that case, you are going to need to add a lot more detail about your environment, files, metadata and the Biml you are using to try and achieve this.  At present there is next to nothing in your question that we can actually use to try and help you.

Comment: I actually forgot to answer, because work moved on and stuff, sorry. I still think the issue is quite clear: how to get the metadata of a pipeline in an SSIS data flow, so that you can write it to a database.

Comment: That is not possible as far as I am aware, certainly not using Biml.  All Biml does is generate the dtsx and associated files that make up an SSIS project, it does not subsequently open and interact with those files.

Comment: Maybe it was confusing, sorry. I do NOT want to generate this metadata WITH BIML, I want to generate it so I can USE it later on in my BIML script.

Comment: Again, I do not think this is possible without hooking into the same .net functions SSIS itself is using to generate it.  Do be aware though, the SSIS generated metadata is far from perfect and in my experience always requires some degree of manual tweaking.  You will be better served simply creating the metadata yourself once and then referencing that in your Biml.  From that point on adding new file formats is not a significant task, assuming you have built a sufficiently generic Biml framework.